# How do I apply dynamic conditions to a Rails 3 has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have three models: RaceCards, Races and Wagers.

```
class RaceCard < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :races
has_many :wagers
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :race_card
has_many :wagers, :through => :race_card
end

class Wager < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :race_card
has_many :races, :through => :race_card
end

rails g model RaceCard race_card_date:date number_of_race:integer

rails g model Race race_card_id:integer race_nbr:integer

rails g model Wager race_nbr:integer race_card_id:integer wager_type:string payoff:integer
```

So if I do this in console:

```
Wager.first.races  #All races on the race card are returned. Good!
```

But I want a way of determining what races are returned so I add a condition:

```
if I add this:   :condition =>{:race_nbr => 1}

Wager.first.races  #Return just race 1, but this is static (always set to 1)
```

My question is how do I set the condition to the race_nbr in the Wager model:

```
:condition => {:race_nbr => wager.race_nbr}  #throws an error
:condition => {:race_nbr => self.race_nbr}   #throws an error
```

I've tried a lot of other things and just can't seem to get it.  Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Update: I've now tried the solution suggested by PinnyM below

```
:condition => "wagers.race_nbr = races.race_nbr" #unfortunately this yields the following:

SQL error or missing database (no such column wagers.race_nbr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using scopes:

```
def Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_race_nbr, lambda { |race_nbr| where(:race_nbr => race_nbr) }
end

def Wager < ActiveRecord::Base
  def races_for_race_nbr
    races.for_race_nbr(race_nbr)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was hoping to put the condition inside the association.  Would something like this work: :condition => {wager_nbr => races.race_nbr}

Comment: I thought we had it, but when I tried in the console I get the following:Wager Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "wagers".* FROM "wagers" WHERE "wagers"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Race Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "races".* FROM "races" INNER JOIN "race_cards" ON "races"."race_card_id" = "race_cards"."id" WHERE "race_cards"."id" = 1 AND (races.race_nbr = wagers.race_nbr)
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: wagers.race_nbr).  It looks like somehow I need to get Wager added to the join.

Comment: You are right, I had incorrectly assumed that the join through was done in 1 step.  Unfortunately, external joins aren't permitted on an association like :has_many.  I think you'll have to resort to using a scope, see answer (edited again).

Comment: Believe it or not, this approach yields the exact same error was the earlier approach.  The join here is also done in multiple steps. First it queries Wagers and gets that first record, next it does an inner join on races and race cards but is unable to resolve the wager.race_nbr reference in the where clause.  Interesting.

Comment: There should not be a reference to wagers.race_nbr because the code doesn't contain any. Are you sure you removed the :conditions modifier and restarted the console environment?

Comment: In your answer above the where clause includes the reference to wagers.race_nbr, yes?

Comment: Right again!  I was actually referring to the new scope approach.  The original answer using :where has the same problem as has_many, although you can add a join to fix it.  The scope method should work for you, can you verify this?